# remove extra characters or a value from column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to remove the '/' and after the '/' value i.e, 25?

sample:

```
   score
    10
    24
    19
    20/25
    18/25
    16/25
```

output:

```
score
10
24
19
20
18
16
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [df.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function here.

```
df['score'] = df['score'].replace('/.*','',regex=True)
```

df will become like:

```
    score
0   10
1   24
2   19
3   20
4   18
5   16
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.extract`:

```py
df['score'] = df['score'].str.extract(r'^(\d+)')
```

Using `str.replace`:

```py
df['score'] = df['score'].str.replace(r'/.*$', '')
```